# Assigning css class to an element using php

Tags: php

I have a blog, which contains the content of a post within a text file. This text file contains plain text and html. The contents are pulled into string called $data. I want to expand functionality of this so I'm trying to I am trying to do two things.

1. Search the $content_blog and assign a 'video' class to every `<p>` element if the `<p>` element contains an `<iframe>` within it. Often video's are added to blog posts and to make the size fit 100% I have a class assigned to the `<p>` element.
2. Search the $content_blog and assign a 'feature_image' class to the first `<img>` element found.

The code for displaying one blog post is

```
if (!(empty($get_id)) && is_numeric($get_id) && $all_blog_files[$get_id]) { 
        $open         = fopen($all_blog_files[$get_id][0] , "r");
        $data         = @fread($open, filesize($all_blog_files[$get_id][0])); fclose($open);
        $lines        = explode("\n", $data);
        $date_explode = explode('-', $lines[2]);
        $month        = $date_explode[0];
        $day          = $date_explode[1];
        $year         = $date_explode[2];
        $date_mk      = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
        $date         = date($date_format, $date_mk);
        $title        = $lines[0];
        // strip special characters from URL
        $title_strip  = str_replace([",","- ", "$", "%", "?", "!"],"", $title);
        //replace latinic characters in URL
        $unwanted_array = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'Đ'=>'Dj', 'đ'=>'dj', 'ć'=>'c', 'Ć'=>'C', 'Č'=>'C', 'č'=>'č', 'Č'=>'C');
        $clean_title = strtr( $title_strip, $unwanted_array );
        $url_title    = $all_blog_files[$postnumber][1].'/'.str_replace(" ", "-", $clean_title);

        $lines     = array_slice($lines,3);
        $content_blog   = implode("\n", $lines);
        $content_blog   = str_replace("##more##", "", $content_blog);
        //$page_title = $title . ' ' . $page_title;
        $page_title = $title. " - Radio Ritam Srca Blog";
        $page_desc = substr(strip_tags($lines[1]), 0, 80). ' ' . $page_desc;
        echo "<div class='blog-wrap'>";
        echo "<h1 class='blog-title'>$title</h1>";
        echo "<p class='blog-date'>$date</p>";
        echo $parsedown->text($content_blog);   
        if ($disqus_comments == true){include('inc/plugins/disqus.php');}
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<a class='btn btn-red' href=\"$previous\">Nazad Na Blog</a>";
}
```

Comment: `if ($all_blog_files[$get_id])` is not how you check if the key exists in the array, it is how you check if the element is truthy AFTER determining that the element exists.  `@` (error suppression) gives code a bad smell.  If you want to read a file line by line, perhaps try `file()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the goal is styling, can you do this more elegantly with a pure CSS solution?

```
p iframe {
   width: 100%;
}

img:first-child {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: for the iframe, I have the following css ```.video {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 padding-bottom: 61%;
}
.video iframe {
 position: absolute;
 width: 98%;
 height:98%;
 left:0;
 top:0; 
}```

and html looks like ```<p class="video"> <iframe src...></p>``` I usually manually add class="video" to every ```<p>``` before the video, so I wanted to automate it.
Regarding the image, I was hoping to assign a class to the first image, then use that image in the og:image meta tag.

Comment: Can you just put those styles into the code I have above? That'd save you from needing to assign classes at all.

Comment: That worked for the iframe part! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, changing my css .video to p, and .video iframe to p iframe affects all the p's in the blog. So that doesn't really work. It seems that for the video iframe to be full width it needs to sit in a wrapper, so either p class something or div class something.

Comment: Is there any structure that allows you to limit the CSS selector further? Such as if all the content where a video might appear was inside of `<div class="content">` you could do something like `.content p iframe`.

Comment: I guess that would be the same as ```<p class="video">```. Still requires me to add the class manually.